# Is it possible to add BoostrapCSS classes on an email layout?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to make a digest e-mail to be sent by crontab using yii/console.

I can manage to send the email already but the layout is not as good because I can't load the bootstrap files needed to use it's classes.

Is it possible to use bootstrap css classes on an email using yii2?

Comment: bootstrap is not designed to be supported by email providers. you should consider building your own templates or using a different CSS framework like [Foundation for Emails](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some background:  What email clients are the intended recipients using?  If it's browser-based, you're going to run into consistency issues with what, say Google or Microsoft, allow as far as the contents of the email, e.g. stripping out `<script>` blocks and such.  IIRC, the use of inline styles is STRONGLY recommended.  [This](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story) is an older article, but many of the tenants still apply.

To answer your question, it may not be worth it for Bootstrap given the size of the CSS - but if you can make it inline styles instead of classes, it may work.  I should also add that unless the development framework specifically adds for a use case like this, I don't think it matters if it's yii or anything else.